# Round down by a specific precision in C#

Tags: c#

How can I round down a `double` by a specific `precision`. I need a function that gets a `double` and returns the closest value to that double that is a multiple of that specific `precision` and is lower than the double.

So for example if the precision = 2.5

```
9.3  ---> 7.5

12.5 ---> 12.5

13.0 ---> 12.5

14.5 ---> 12.5

15.5 ---> 15.0
```

Comment: round down what? can you explain it clearly

Comment: I want the function to round the number N to the nearest multiple of the 2.5 which is also lower than N. I happened to find the answer for this. I guess I asked too early :(

Comment: Like this? `((int)(number/precision))*precision`

Comment: @Reniuz Thanks, (int) would work too, but which one is faster? (int) or Math.Floor?

Comment: It is better to use Math.Floor. I just posted quick idea. Use korneyev answer for couple of reasons: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9802978/math-floor-vs-cast-to-an-integral-type-in-c-sharp ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Math.Floor(value / precision) * precision
```