# Is there any benefit to using Math.Floor over explicit integer casting?

Tags: java, c#, math, casting, floor

Question is pretty straightforward, is there any benefit or difference? I've noticed that in C# the function returns a double without any decimal places, while in java it keeps the decimal places, but other than that the result is the same.

Here is the code I used in Java and C#, and the output:

```
//Java                                        //C#

double a = 5.5;                               double a = 5.5;
System.out.println(Math.floor(a));            Console.WriteLine(Math.Floor(a));
System.out.println((int)a);                   Console.WriteLine((int)a);

//Output                                      //Output

5.0                                           5
5                                             5
```

Comment: Java prints `.0` to all floats I guess.

Comment: you're making assumption `java it keeps` based on output of system.out? it is wrong assumption

Comment: `Math.Floor` returns a double without the decimal part. It's not the same as casting to integer

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/9802978/3970411

Comment: `int` has a lower possible magnitude than `float` or `double`.

Comment: @Matthew: good point, inserted this in the answer.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Yes**, for **negative** numbers, this works in the opposite way.

**Example** (using Mono's C# interactive shell `csharp`):

```
csharp> Math.Floor(-12.0d)
-12
csharp> Math.Floor(-12.5d) 
-13
csharp> (int) -12.5
-12
```

(same for both Java/C#) and I guess most languages anyway.

**Casting** a floating-point number to an integer, is performed by throwing away the decimal part maintaining the integer part. The integer part of `-12.5` is `12`. Thus negative numbers do a `Math.Ceil` if converted to an `int`.

Furthermore as @Matthew argues, a `float` or `double` can reach numbers like `1.023e23` (*Avogadro's constant)*. Simply because the *mantisse* can't represent digits after the comma anymore. Numbers that *are* considered to be an integer anyway, but can't be represented by an `int`. By performing a `Math.floor` operation, nothing happens, but the value is still maintained. While conversion to an `int` could result in **overflow**:

**Example**:

```
csharp> double ac = 1.023e23;
csharp> Math.Floor(ac);
1.023E+23
csharp> (int) ac;
0
```

> Note: this may look far fetched, but there is thus a clear difference in semantics nevertheless. A difference that tends to lead to errors anyway.

In addition, it [works differently](http://ideone.com/a9RU27) for **infinite** numbers and [NaN](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#NaN):

```
System.out.println(Math.floor(Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY)); // Prints Infinity
System.out.println((int)Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY);        // Prints 2147483647
System.out.println(Math.floor(Double.NaN));               // Prints NaN
System.out.println((int)Double.NaN);                      // Prints 0
```

But I would always use them nevertheless. Casting makes things way more unreadable. Rounding up/down/off is more some kind of (side-effect) of the cast. By using `Math.Ceil/Floor/Round` it is clear what you mean.

Sometimes a cast to an integer is indeed a bit more efficient than performing a floor/ceil operation first. But a smart compiler can sometimes derive that a variable will always store a positive number and thus optimize it itself. And furthermore for most applications this will result in an insignificant performance penalty.